# eps figure fitting not exactly inside the \textwidth

Tags: pdf, geometry, eps, unit-of-measure

There is a ***.eps** figure of size exactly **6.5inch by 6.5inch** (no white borders). This figure needs to be placed exactly inside the document, which has a `\textwidth` = 6.5".

Logically the *.eps should completely occupy the `\textwidth` space (which is exactly 6.5in) but due to some unknown reasons there remains a room left (few `pt`) in output `*.pdf` as shown below.

(The *.eps figure is not to be scaled, as its physical dimensions (inches) need to be preserved in final publishing.)

LuaTex with TexLive is used.

[image]
minimal example:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\overfullrule=1mm
\documentclass[11pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn,conference]{IEEEtran} 

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
%\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{layout}


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} 
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{setspace}

%\usepackage{showkeys}
%\usepackage[disable,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[obeyDraft,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\usepackage[section]{placeins} % it keeps the figures in the respective section
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor=Green4,
    linkcolor  = blue
}


\pagebreak


% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  % \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  % \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
% graphicx was written by David Carlisle and Sebastian Rahtz. It is
% required if you want graphics, photos, etc. graphicx.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation can
% be obtained at: 



% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{}


\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h]
%   \centering
%   \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=6.5in,height=6.5in,keepaspectratio]{out.eps}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{f02}
 \end{figure} 

\layout
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `\centering` sufficient?

Comment: Are you sure the boundingbox is strictly to the edge of the image? You can use `\fbox{\includegraphics...} ` as a test to see if the boundingbox is wrong (and thus is including more white space on one side compared to the other)

Comment: If the image should not be scaled you should remove `[width=6.5in,height=6.5in,keepaspectratio]`

Comment: What is the %%BoundingBox comment in out.eps ?

Comment: @daleif You are right. When I replaced the .eps with .pdf of the figure, it fits perfectly. It is strange to me, the same matlab figure when saved with .eps is different than its .pdf format.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle boundingbox is the layout of the class IEEETrans.

Comment: @Bernard \centering is doing nothing.

Comment: no I mean the comment `%%BoundingBox: a b c d` in the EPS file that tells latex how big it is

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know this much detail. Would you please tell where to check it?

Comment: just look in the file, usually near the top somewhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle %%BoundingBox:     0     0   472   472

Comment: so it is bigger than 6.5in (6.55555... to be exact) so you have to decide whether to scale it to 6.5in wide or not.

Comment: I tried hard to come up with .eps figure (from matlab) that would not add extra border but no success. I don't tweak after the .eps file has been generated because of the possible inaccuracy that may result with manual hands. So, I think that instead of *.eps , *pdf is better.

Comment: I think the problem was:`1/72` inch is `pt` in EPS, but a big point `bp` in TeX. I need to check it, though.